# python 2.7 : How to grep/split lines containing pattern

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a log file as

```
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>DEBUG 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
WARNING 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>ERROR 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
```

Now, this file cannot be properly split on `\n`, i.e. If i want to read the individual messages, i can split the file content on `\n` and iterate.

So, i need to split on some pattern like

`[INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR]<timestamp>`

How can i form a regular expression to achieve this? Also, i would still need the log level and timestamp information after splitting. So i guess i need to create some form of grep

How can i achieve this in python?

I tried this pattern

`(INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR) \d{2}\/\d{2}\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s[A|P]M`

but i dont get any matches

Comment: What regular expression have you tried?

Comment: Is it possible for INFO/DEBUG/WARNING/ERROR to appear in <some message>?

Comment: no, the log level only appears at beginning

Comment: i updated my post with a pattern i tried

Comment: You are missing \/ after the second d{2}

Comment: Your pattern has a typo between the day and year, and escaping the slashes is not needed: `\d{2}\/\d{2}\d{4}` should be `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}`

Comment: Tip: at https://regex101.com/ you can test your regular expressions on the test data you supply and see how it works. Very convenient!

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this:

- Find: `(?<!\n)(?=INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR)`
- Replace: `\n`

This will insert a linebreak before `INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR` if it is not preceded by a linebreak.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3JKYpc/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the assumptions for the regex:

- a message must start with a level, a space, at date, a space and a time
- the text for the message starts after a space and continues until the beginning of next message or the end of the string
- the message has to be splitted in 3 parts: the level, the datedate, and the text. The spaces and an optional ending `\n` are not included in the parts.

The regex is:

```
trx = r'(INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR) (\d{2}\/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s[AP]M) (.*?)\n?(?=(?:INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR)|$)'
```

Demo:

```
import re

t = '''INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>DEBUG 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
WARNING 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>ERROR 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>'''

msg = re.compile(r'(INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR) (\d{2}\/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s[AP]M) '
                 '(.*?)\n?(?=(?:INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR)|$)', re.DOTALL)

pprint(msg.findall(t))
```

gives:

```
[('INFO', '01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM', '<some message>'),
 ('INFO', '01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM', '<some message>'),
 ('INFO', '01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM', '<some message>'),
 ('DEBUG', '01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM', '<some message>'),
 ('INFO', '01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM', '<some message>'),
 ('INFO', '01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM', '<some message>'),
 ('WARNING', '01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM', '<some message>'),
 ('ERROR', '01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM', '<some message>')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use substitution to simply insert a new line in front of each occurrence of the pattern and then split on "\n"

```
data = """INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>DEBUG 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
WARNING 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>ERROR 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>"""

import re
pattern   = r"(?<!^)(?<!\n)(WARNING|DEBUG|ERROR|INFO) ([0-9\/:]* ){2}(AM|PM) "
splitData = re.sub(pattern,r"\n\g<0>",data).split("\n")
for line in splitData:
    print(line)

INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
DEBUG 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
WARNING 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
ERROR 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
```

*Note I simplified the pattern under the assumption that the time stamp will always contain 2 numeric parts separated by a space followed by AM or PM. You can adjust the expression to be more specific. Or you could simply skip the time stamp part and only use the keywords but then you have to be certain that the messages don't contain any of these keywords*

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use an expression with multiple capturing groups and collect what we wish to, maybe with an expression similar to:

```
(INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR)\s+?(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s+?(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+?([A-Z]{2})\s+?(<(.+?)>)
```

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR)\s+?(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s+?(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+?([A-Z]{2})\s+?(<.+?>)"

test_str = ("INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>\n"
    "INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>DEBUG 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>\n"
    "INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>\n"
    "WARNING 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>ERROR 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U1HCtw/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Demo

This snippet just shows that how the capturing groups work:

```js
const regex = /(INFO|DEBUG|WARNING|ERROR)\s+?(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s+?(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+?([A-Z]{2})\s+?(<.+?>)/gm;
const str = `INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>DEBUG 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>INFO 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>
WARNING 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>ERROR 01/23/2019 01:49:48 PM <some message>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this is really helpful, but how do i capture the text between matches?

Comment: thanks, but i dont think the lower snippet is in python. which language is it? and how can i replicate in python?